# Get HTTP 400 Bad Request when login using Python requests

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `requests` to log into https://appleid.apple.com/cn (/us should be the same, but get 400 Bad request returned.

```
session = requests.Session()

productURL = <the URL above>

headers = {
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
            "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
        }
session.headers = headers
r = session.get(productURL)

url = "//idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=af1139274f266b22b68c2a3e7ad932cb3c0bbe854e13a79af78dcc73136882c3&language=zh_CN&rv=1"
r = session.get(url)

url = "//idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin"
headers = {
        "Accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        "Content-Length":"77",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Host":"idmsa.apple.com",
        "Origin":"https://idmsa.apple.com",
        "Referer":"//idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=af1139274f266b22b68c2a3e7ad932cb3c0bbe854e13a79af78dcc73136882c3&language=zh_CN&rv=1",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Apple-Domain-Id":1,
        "X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info":{"U":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36","L":"en-US","Z":"GMT+08:00","V":"1.1","F":"7da44j1e3NlY5BSo9z4ofjb75PaK4Vpjt4U_98uszHVyVxFAk.lzXJJIneGffLMC7EZ3QHPBirTYKUowRslz8eibjVdxljQlpQJuYY9hte_1an92r5xj6KksmfTPdFdgmVxf7_OLgiPFMJhHFW_jftckkCoqAkCoq4ly_0x0uVMV0jftckcKyAd65hz7fwdGEM6uJ6o6e0T.5EwHXXTSHCSPmtd0wVYPIG_qvoPfybYb5EtCKoxw4EiCvTDfPbJROKjCJcJqOFTsrhsui65KQnK94CaJ6hO3f9p_nH1zDz.ICMpwoNSdqdbAE9XXTneNufuyPBDjaY2ftckuyPB884akHGOg429OMNo71xFmrur.S9RdPQSzOy_Aw7UTlf_0pNA1OXu_Llri5Ly.EKY.6ekL3sdmX.Cr_Jz9KyFxv5icCmVug4WBkl1BQLz4mvmfTT9oaSumKkpjlRiwerbXh8bUu_LzQW5BNv_.BNlYCa1nkBMfs.Byn"},
        "X-Apple-Locale":"zh_CN",
        "X-Apple-Widget-Key":"af1139274f266b22b68c2a3e7ad932cb3c0bbe854e13a79af78dcc73136882c3",
        "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
        }
session.headers = headers

payload = {
            "accountName" : "accountName",
            "password" : "password",
            "rememberMe" : False
        }
r = session.post(url, params=payload)
```

#### Headers info

request headers

```
{
  'Content-Length': '77',
  'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info': {
    'F': '7da44j1e3NlY5BSo9z4ofjb75PaK4Vpjt4U_98uszHVyVxFAk.lzXJJIneGffLMC7EZ3QHPBirTYKUowRslz8eibjVdxljQlpQJuYY9hte_1an92r5xj6KksmfTPdFdgmVxf7_OLgiPFMJhHFW_jftckkCoqAkCoq4ly_0x0uVMV0jftckcKyAd65hz7fwdGEM6uJ6o6e0T.5EwHXXTSHCSPmtd0wVYPIG_qvoPfybYb5EtCKoxw4EiCvTDfPbJROKjCJcJqOFTsrhsui65KQnK94CaJ6hO3f9p_nH1zDz.ICMpwoNSdqdbAE9XXTneNufuyPBDjaY2ftckuyPB884akHGOg429OMNo71xFmrur.S9RdPQSzOy_Aw7UTlf_0pNA1OXu_Llri5Ly.EKY.6ekL3sdmX.Cr_Jz9KyFxv5icCmVug4WBkl1BQLz4mvmfTT9oaSumKkpjlRiwerbXh8bUu_LzQW5BNv_.BNlYCa1nkBMfs.Byn',
    'Z': 'GMT+08:00',
    'U': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
    'L': 'en-US',
    'V': '1.1',
  },
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'X-Apple-Widget-Key': 'af1139274f266b22b68c2a3e7ad932cb3c0bbe854e13a79af78dcc73136882c3',
  'Origin': '//idmsa.apple.com',
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
  'Host': 'idmsa.apple.com',
  'X-Apple-Domain-Id': 1,
  'Referer': '//idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=af1139274f266b22b68c2a3e7ad932cb3c0bbe854e13a79af78dcc73136882c3&language=zh_CN&rv=1',
  'X-Apple-Locale': 'zh_CN',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

response headers

```
{
  'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block',
  'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
  'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src *; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.apple.com https://*.cdn-apple.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://*.apple.com https://*.cdn-apple.com; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://*.apple.com https://*.cdn-apple.com https://*.icloud.com https://*.mzstatic.com; media-src * data:;",
  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
  'Set-Cookie': 'dslang=CN-ZH; Domain=.apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, site=CHN; Domain=.apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly',
  'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT',
  'Server': 'Apple',
  'Connection': 'close',
  'X-BuildVersion': 'R15',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store',
  'Date': 'Sat, 01 Oct 2016 04:23:19 GMT',
  'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'DENY',
}
```

I checked all the headers field with the real request headers, "X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info" is the only one not correct. Dig a little bit, it was calculated by javascript. 'Z','U','L','V' are constant, depends on you browser info and timezone etc. But the 'F' is a very long random string

- Is "X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info" the problem result in 400 Bad request?
- Is this the right way to write something like auto login? By compareing request headers and cookies one by one?
- Is it possible to generate or skip header "X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info"?
- How can I get this auto login work?

Comment: Since the the reputation limit for new users, I have to remove the 'https' from URLs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are posting JSON you should use requests like:

```
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

also, don't need to hardcode the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` requests package takes care of that.

Comment: You are right. Apparently I missed this part in the doc. Is `data=json.dumps(payload)` the same with `json=payload`?

Comment: json=payload  is newer other than that they are same, they both set content type to application/json and handle encoding.

Comment: Both of `json` and `data` returned 200, but only `json` logged in successfully.  `data` jumped back to login page. Is there any way I can check the posted data with the real request? Went through the API doc, didn't find any.

Comment: dirty way to do it: `vim $(dirname $(python -c "import requests;print requests.__file__"))/models.py` and add a `print body` at the end of `prepare_body` method

Comment: thanks, this helped me as well. Here is the documentation on POST requests with JSON: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new and can't comment (I don't quite understand the reputation system yet), I'll have to write an answer.

I know that Google recently blocked the login via scripts (well, via most scripts) because it was rather easy to conduct brute force attacks against accounts.

I am presuming that Apple did something very similar and thus making it hard to log onto the AppleId. Do you know for sure that it is possible to login that way?

Greetings,
Narusan

Comment: Hi Narusan, actually just as Nima Ghotbi said, wrong parameter problem. This scared header `X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info` did nothing, at least for login. I removed it from the headers. Now the login works

Comment: Ok, great to know. Sorry for that then. Have fun experimenting with it!